# Typescript generic mapped type for function return type

Tags: javascript, typescript

How does one go about generic mapped type for function result. I have a generic function that gets a property of some other global object, uses it to access the object and calls the returned function. I can get it properly typed if I don't call the function, but calling it breaks the typing.

```js
const dict = {
  "foo": () => 1,
  "bar": () => "1"
} as const;

function getData<Key extends keyof typeof dict>(foobar: Key): ReturnType<typeof dict[Key]> {
  return dict[foobar](); // Type string | number is not assignable to type ReturnType<{   readonly foo: () => number;   readonly bar: () => string; }[key]>
}
```

It works just fine if it's not a function though.

```js
const dict = { "foo": 1, "bar": "1" } as const;
function getData<Key extends keyof typeof dict>(foobar: Key): typeof dict[Key] {
  return dict[foobar];
}
```

Comment: `const dict = { "foo": 1, "bar": ():string => "1" } as const;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still some kind of limitation in TS. Workarounds according to this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)

```
const dict = {
  "foo": () => 1,
  "bar": () => "1"
} as const;

type dictReturnTypeMap = {
  [K in keyof typeof dict]: ReturnType<typeof dict[K]>
}

let _dict: {[K in keyof dictReturnTypeMap]: ()=>dictReturnTypeMap[K]} = dict;

function getData<Key extends keyof dictReturnTypeMap>(foobar: Key): ReturnType<typeof dict[Key]> {
  return _dict[foobar]();
}
```